# What does 'subscribe' in the Stack Exchange Shiny Hover Tag Information-o-Matic do?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, subscription, tag-bubble

Now that tags have this erm... [shiny thing](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/439709#439709) which appears when you move your mouse over them (try it! [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles)), one question remains: What in the billion blue blazes does the 'subscribe' button do?

It's not RSS, since a traditional RSS feed link appears beside it, and clicking on it seems to increment the number of subscriber by one, but other than that scouring over the Stack Overflow UI does not appear to reveal anything. Surely this feature would have more use than serving as a popularity contest for the tags?

Comment: So it seems that this is no longer there - the functionality changed a bit: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135) For people who are curious, here a screenshot showing how it looked like is, for example, here: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it allows you to quickly set up email notifications for a given tag.

Also, it gives a reason to give premium visibility to tag wikis, which is great.

I don't think the subscriber count should be given that much importance; a question count would have more appropriate. Alas, that's a matter for another [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I noticed that too when I rested my mouse on the subscribe button for the [waffles] tag. Hmm... I think I'll unsubscribe now