# How to subscribe to tags?

Tags: support, tags, email-notification, tag-filters, subscription

There used to be "subscribe" button in the popup window which appears when you hover the mouse over a tag. It then sent you a confirmation e-mail and later it was sending e-mail feeds when new question tagged with the tag appeared.

The "subscribe" button is not there anymore. How can I subscribe to the e-mail notifications?

[image: old tag popup window with "subscribe" and "rss" links]

Old duplicate question: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags)

Comment: See the comments under https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312247 for a workaround until the new Tag Watching enables this feature

Answer (score 5):

According to ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/295232), subscribing to tags will be replaced with a Notifications feature, which will have some configuration options in addition. However, it hasn't been rolled out yet.

Until then (thanks @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ), you can use the workaround described by Joe Friend in the comments to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312247):

> - If you want to subscribe to updates for ALL your fav tags on all sites, then there is a way around this. Go to: https://stackexchange.com/filters. Click on "Favorite Tags" under "Select Filter" in the right sidebar. Then click "Subscribe" to received email updates (again, right sidebar) and choose your subscription prefs.
> - Next step is to click on your profile, click on "subscriptions" and unsubscribe from any one-off favorite tag subscriptions.